# Sending data with 9600 baud at AT89S52, 4Mhz crystal

Tags: timer, serial-port, microcontroller

Mates,

I want to transmit data using AT89S52 and my crystal is 4 Mhz,
Am I writing a correct baud rate code below ?
Or anyone of you know how to calculate a baud rate ?

Thanks a lot

```
void transmit_data()
 {
    TMOD = 0x20;
    TH1 = 0xfd;
    PCON &= 0x7f;
SCON = 0x50;
TCON =0x40;
while(1)
  {
    printf("a"); // transmit a along with CR & LF.
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a calculator to help:
http://www.keil.com/c51/baudrate.asp
Unfortunately, it shows how poor a 4 MHz crystal selection is for standard baud rates.

Comment: which "Serial Clock Divisor:" should I use for my code above ? thanks, may be I can change to my 11Mhz or 24Mhz crystal

Comment: If you use the configuration described at the top of the calculator page and a 11.0592 Mhz crystal, the reload value should be 0FDh

Answer (score 1):

Code it up with some guesstimate values and send 0xAA in a loop.  Look at the tx o/p with a scope, measure the bit width and then err... 'optimize' the divisor values.  This has some advantages over finding/reading/digesting the huge user manual and calculating:

1) It's quicker, unless you're lucky.

2) If there is no output at all, you get to fix the dodgy hardware and/or incorrect UART initializion and/or register addresses and/or pin assignments before spending ages wondering what you did wrong with the baud rate.

3) It always works, even if the user manual baud rate formula is 'less than 100% correct'.

4) When you can see the output coming out correctly but there is still no communication, you can blame it on the cables and/or DCE/DTE and/or Hyperterminal and/or all the other stuff that stops RS232 working.

Comment: do you know how to calculate the baudrate with 4Mhz clock ?thanks

Comment: 0x55 which is a capital U also works.  Without a scope if you are a power of two off, you can connect to a computer and try slowing the baud rate down until it works.  No guarantees but helps for common mistakes like not knowing about a divide by 2 or 4 somewhere in the hardware.

Comment: i can see the simulation is working on Keil, but I can't see the result when I connect my serial port in laptop into serial port at the circuit, how can I know MAX 232 is working or not ?

Comment: If you have no scope, you could connect a LED through a resistor, (guess-4.7K), across pins 2 & 7, (tx data and gnd).  If you alternately output what should be a seconds worth of 0x00 and a seconds worth of 0xFF, the LED should flash.  If the LED flashes too fast or too slow, you baud rate is too fast/slow.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can get for 9600 baut is using 11.0592Mhz Crystal...0% error margin